# Printing form feed character in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, ascii, page-break

According to this page running `print "Hello\fworld"`  should give `hello` and `page` printed on different lines and with different indentations (something of a page break which is the purpose of the form feed character). However when I do `print("Hello\fworld")` in Python 3, what I get is the female sign: `Hello♀world`, which is what I also get when I run `print(u"Hello\u2640world")`. How is that?

Comment: why should `"Hello\fworld"` print `page`? Typo?

Comment: ```print("Hello\fworld")```  in python3.8.2 print ```Hello``` and, in a new line, ```world```. https://repl.it/repls/ConstantAdmirablePyramid#main.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows console and IDLE or whatever stdout you are using dosen't support form feed characters, so you can't print them to stdout.